# c++ opengGL: Draw polygon + image processing interior pixels

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing, draw, gldrawpixels

I am using opengl and c++ doing image processing. The idea is simple, I will load an image, draw a polygon by clicking and then apply an effect (desaturation for instance) only to the pixels in the interior of the polygon shape just created.

Can anyone give me any direction on how to limit the effect to the pixels within the interior of the polygon? Loading the image and drawing the polygon is not a problem

Comment: Stencil buffer not work?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the following situation :

- The picture on which you want to apply the effect takes the whole screen
- The picture is rendered using opengl , probably through a simple shader, with the picture passed as a texture

You can do the following approach :

- consider the screen as being a big texture
- you draw a polygon, which will be rendered on top of the rendered texture
- inside the polygon's vertices insert the uv's coresponding to the 2D coordinates on the screen (so from screen space to uv space (0 , 1 ) )
- draw the picture normaly
- on top of the picture draw your polygon using the same picture as texture, but with a different shader

So instead of trying to desaturate a specific region from your picture, create a polygon on top of that region with the same picture, and desaturate that new polygon.

This would help you in avoiding the stencil buffer.

Another approach would be to create the polygon, but draw it only on the stencil buffer, before the picture is drawn.

Comment: Here is a pic of what I want to do. I am using OPENGL and C++. I have the blur effect done but I want to restrict it to my selection. Example: http://postimg.org/image/8e83s4v05/

Comment: The approach above solves your problem. Just render a new polygon on top of the picture with different UVs to match the selection position. The new polygon , render it with the blur shader.

Comment: I understand. Will this method works if the polygon is a shape of more than 4 vertexes? something like this http://postimg.org/image/voadbmbjp/ and THANKS!!

Comment: This method will work regardless of the polygon's shape or vertexes number. You just need to assign the correct uvs to the vertices (and positions ofc ). Also keep in mind that the order of the vertices count in order to determine the triangle's normal. I suggest you make a very quick test of your polygon generation by rendering an red polygon over a black background.

Comment: This is the output I am getting. The scaled image is the polygon I drew http://postimg.org/image/iseohi5it/ THat should be cropped and not scaled. Can anyone give me a tutorial for getting the UV of that specific texture area for applying the blur effect? THANKS

Comment: Well, it will appear correctly once you compute the right uvs.